# How to plot a contour of an image in python if I have an image?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have an image of an chicken for which I have to plot the contour. I'm getting an error (attached below). What does the error mean and how to rectify it?

This is the error I'm getting for this code:

Code:

```
img = color.rgb2gray(io.imread('chic1.png'))

img = np.flip(img, axis=0)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1956/2147137072.py in <module>
----> 1 img = color.rgb2gray(io.imread('chic1.png'))
      2 img = np.flip(img, axis=0)

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\_shared\utils.py in fixed_func(*args, **kwargs)
    392 
    393             if channel_axis is None:
--> 394                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
    395 
    396             # TODO: convert scalars to a tuple in anticipation of eventually

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\color\colorconv.py in rgb2gray(rgb, channel_axis)
    873     >>> img_gray = rgb2gray(img)
    874     """
--> 875     rgb = _prepare_colorarray(rgb)
    876     coeffs = np.array([0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721], dtype=rgb.dtype)
    877     return rgb @ coeffs

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\color\colorconv.py in _prepare_colorarray(arr, force_copy, channel_axis)
    138         msg = (f'the input array must have size 3 along `channel_axis`, '
    139                f'got {arr.shape}')
--> 140         raise ValueError(msg)
    141 
    142     float_dtype = _supported_float_type(arr.dtype)

ValueError: the input array must have size 3 along `channel_axis`, got (251, 402, 4)
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw23I.png)

[The image I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIjI8.png)

Comment: I think your io.imread returns an alpha channel as the 4th color value. If you slice it like [:, :, :3] it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your image includes an alpha channel. Thus, the shape of your input image is `(251, 402, 4)`. But [`rgb2gray()`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html#skimage.color.rgb2gray) expects an image with 3 channels only.

You could simply strip the alpha channel (as suggested by @Imielke) or use `rgba2rgb()` first. The later supports [alpha-bleeding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Alpha_blending) (if needed).

```
from skimage import color, io

img_4d = io.imread('chic1.png')

#alternative 1
img = color.rgba2rgb(img_4d)
img_gray = color.rgb2gray(img)

#alternative 2
img_gray = color.rgb2gray(img_4d[:, :, :3])

...
```

Answer (score 0):

io.imread says the following in the docstring:

```
Returns
    -------
    img_array : ndarray
        The different color bands/channels are stored in the
        third dimension, such that a gray-image is MxN, an
        RGB-image MxNx3 and an RGBA-image MxNx4.
```

You should only provide the colors and not the alpha which io.imread() supplies:

```
img = color.rgb2gray(io.imread('chic1.png')[:,:,:3])
```

However you could also just use skimage imread to change it to grayscale in one go:

```
img = io.imread('chic1.png', as_gray=True)
img = np.flip(img, axis=0)
```